# Upgrade from 5.4 to 6 not supported from built in upgrader

Tags: upgrade, ee5

My installation doesn't seem to support the built-in upgrader for the 5.4 to 6.0 jump. Previous upgrades worked nicely. Is this what everyone else is seeing too? I don't see this issue reflected in the docs.

Screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/BluYXPLE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't see the integrated updater being flagged, but presumably you know that you can [upgrade the installation manually](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/updating.html) - not really so complicated.

HTH